# networkx: giving a wrong direction for an edge

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to read some dataframe to a networkx graph like this:

```
bipartGraph = nx.Graph()
bipartGraph.add_edge(618254814, 14337833)
bipartGraph.add_edge(618254882, 12087274)
```

When I display the edges using the bipartGraph.edges() function, I get the below:

[(14337833, 618254814), (618254882, 12087274)]

So, the direction of the first edge is reversed. I am trying to build a bipartite graph from  a dataframe which I need to reuse to build an another graph. Is there any specific property of networkx I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in networkx 1.11 if your graph is undirected, an edge that is added as `(u,v)` may be returned as either `(v,u)` or `(u,v)`.  [I think this may have been changed in version 2.0].  This is because the underlying data structure is a dict, and there is no guarantee that a dict returns values in any particular order: [Why items order in a dictionary changed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20192950/2966723).

If you really want a direction on your edge, you should make your graph a DiGraph.