# Reorder a dictionary based on a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have a python dictionary `{apple: 15, orange: 22, juice: 7, blueberry:19}` and I want to reorder the dictionary according to the order of this list `[juice, orange, blueberry, apple]`. How would I do this cleanly/efficiently?
Note: the list could very well have more items than the dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered in python - do you want to pull out the values in a specific order?

Comment: Why would you want to reorder a dictionary? Dictionaries are unordered, so it doesn't matter what order it's in

Comment: @F.M Dictionaries have guaranteed stable iterable order since Python 3.6.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: Technically, it's only a language guarantee as of 3.7, but yes, CPython and PyPy (the only two implementations of Python that have reached 3.6 to my knowledge) both include insertion-ordered `dict`s as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

O(n) method is to simply loop over your list of ordered `keys`:

```
{k: d[k] for k in keys}
```

If you want to maintain the same mutable reference to the dictionary (for whatever reason), just delete the key and add it in a loop. It will naturally order itself correctly.

Comment: There's no guarantee the order will be maintained in this method. You would have to sort the dictionary each time the order mattered. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192950/why-items-order-in-a-dictionary-changed-in-python

Comment: Python 3.6+ dictionaries are all insertion-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, dictionaries don't have an order in Python. Assuming you want to get the dictionary values in the same order as the list, you could do something like this. It checks to see if the key is in the dictionary first, so extra items in the list won't matter

```
d = {apple: 15, orange: 22, juice: 7, blueberry:19}
order = [juice, orange, blueberry, apple]
for key in order:
    if key in d:
        print(d[key])
```

Alternatively as @ewong mentioned, you can use an OrderedDict, which tracks the order a key is added. It [seems like](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86294/reordering-ordereddict) to re-order one you have to create a new OrderedDict, so in your case you could potentially create one from your original dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_d = OrderedDict([(key, d[key]) for key in order if key in d])
```

Comment: or the OP can use ```collections.OrderedDict```